# redis for asp.net mvc, client options?

Tags: redis

I am considering using redis for asp.net mvc application, there is no question about production viability of redis itself, i think it's battle tested.

But there is no mention of it anywhere in .net world, only client i can find is from redis site is servicestackredis for c#.

**So question is have you used redis for .net application? Is servicestackredis production ready? Any other alternative client for redis?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using ServiceStack for a while and find it pretty good, particularly the typed client stuff. I have found bugs in it in the past, but it's well maintained so they don't last for long.

You'll probably want to set up some of your own wrapper classes on top of it though - otherwise you end up with hardcoded keys and connection info in far too many places.

Comment: Hi you should be able to use the thread-safe PooledRedisClientManager or BasicRedisClientManager to keep all your connection config in the 1 place (i.e. your IOC). Otherwise feel free to leave an issue/feature request of what you'd like added to the library

Answer (score 1):

Wish you can get useful infomation from this post: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=474

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this?: http://github.com/migueldeicaza/redis-sharp/blob/master/README[link text](http://github.com/migueldeicaza/redis-sharp/blob/master/README)